# My router is opened to the internet

Tags: wifi

I typed in my IP into my address bar and my router admin page came up. Is this safe? How can I disable it? It's Linksys Smart Wifi

Comment: If your IP address started with 10.*, 192.168.*, or 172.16.* through 172.31.*, or was 127.0.0.1, those aren't internet addresses.  Make sure it's the IP address you see from a "What is my IP" type site.

Comment: Using the public ip doesn't tell if the port(s) are exposed externally, the firewall in many home routers treats internally sourced traffic differently. To be sure you are (or aren't) exposed publicly, it needs to be tested from outside your network.

Comment: Enter your IP into one of the external web page renderers, such as e.g. [this one](http://www.dotcom-monitor.com/WebTools/website-speed-test.aspx), select a server from where you'd like to check it (a single one would do), enter CAPTCHA and run it. If you see your router's service pages (likely a login dialog), it's misconfigured and allows remote admin (so either disable that and reboot the router, or ask a friend to do it for you), or the page rendered will look like an inaccessible page and you're fine and the router's config isn't accessible from WAN.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may already be safe: if you typed your IP address into the address bar of a computer connected to the router, being able to access the router admin page is normal.  The router knows your computer is on the "inside" part of the network, and should be allowed to control the router.

The only time you have a problem is if you type your IP address into a computer somewhere else on the Internet (such as at your local library) and your router admin page shows up: in that case, you need to disable remote administration through the admin page.

Comment: Alternately, use any VPN provider or [TAILS](https://tails.boum.org/) to try and get to your external IP address.  WARNING: The endpoint owner/VPN owner gets to see this traffic.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a little safe if the password is something you only know and is not default such as admin. It would be best to go into your control panel and disable remote management if there is no reason for you to access this over the internet and other people too. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

You're most probably in a private network IP range. It is not accessible through public network (Internet)

Answer (score 0):

Search online for website that can scan your public IP for open ports for you, or ask a friend to do it for you. In latter case, search for software for "port scanning", "penetration testing" or so.
I would run Nmap (with Zenmap GUI) for starters on mine.